# Proving a Hash in Another Hash

Tags: hash

I'm new to cryptography in general, and have this basic question.

Provided  `H(x)` means a hash of `x`
and `z = H(H(x) + H(y))`

given `y` or `H(y)`, how do we prove that `y` or `H(y)` is a part of `z`? How do we "split" `z` into `H(x)` and `H(y)` so that we can compare `H(y)` to our `y`?

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are your security requirements? I'm assuming you do not want to reveal `x`. What about `H(x)`? What are your communication requirements? I.e., could you have an online protocol or does it have to be non-interactive?

Comment: @mikeazo thanks great question. `x` and `H(x)` shouldn't be revealed. `H(x)` should only be necessary for the validation. This is part of the a merkle tree validation. The server retains a merkle tree, and a client can send a request containing data `y` (this can be the data at the leaf or an intermediate hash in the tree `H(y')`) and a linked list of hash strings representing the link from `y` to the root hash. The server then validates by recursively proving that `H(y')` is valid all the way up to the root hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean `H` to be a one-way function. The way you 'prove' that you know half of the input of a one-way function (i.e. `y` or `H(y)` for the outer `H()`) will be to produce the other half of the input (i.e. `x` or `H(x)`) and show that `H()` of the two parts together gives you `z`.

In general, if your `H` is a Pseudo-random-function (which any good crypto-hash function is), then ANY possible combination of `y` and `z` has an infinite number of `x`s that will combine in the way you ask.

Comment: Make sense. So there's no way to validate `y` against `H(H(x)+H(y))` without the knowledge of `x`.